# How fix val field initialization with Spring Security proxy?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, kotlin

Consider kotlin controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myPath/")
open class MyController {
    private val s3AsyncClient: S3AsyncClient = S3AsyncClient.builder().build()
    //...
    @PostMapping("/indexing")
    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    fun someFunction() {
        return s3AsyncClient.toString();
    }
}
```

Which leads to NullPointerException.

Here is what I saws in debugger:

[image]

But when `@Secured` is removed everything works. So it seems that spring security proxing breaks kotlin val initialization. is there a way to make them works all together?

Comment: Could you try `@PreAuthorize ("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` instead of `@Secured("ROLE_USER")`.

Comment: It works! But what is the difference?

Comment: I answered the that. If it works then you can accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: Added a comment to answer, `@PreAuthorize` does not work because it leads to no proxy genertion.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that by default kotlin mark all methods as `final`. So the methods can not be overrided and that's why it is called from object itself, not from proxies. So to make proxying work just add `open` key word in method definition:

```
@PostMapping("/indexing")
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
/* -> */ open fun someFunction() {
    return s3AsyncClient.toString();
}
```